# Looking for a way to delete files in a directory depending on their extension's case

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I would love your help with a tool that would greatly simplify my life. As of now I have no scripting knowledge. I am not sure which of powershell or a .bat is the best suited to my need :

I have a folder with thousands of little files with various extension names. Sometimes I need to delete all the files that have their extension written in uppercase, sometimes the ones in lowercase.

I need a script that would ask me in input if I want to delete Upper or Lowercase files and then would go deleting all the files in the folder with an extension in Upper or Lowercase (based on the input).

I have no idea where to begin. Could you please share some ideas ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your question is off topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the `-match` regular expression operator. Since PowerShell operators always defaults to case-*in*sensitive string comparison, we'll need to qualify it with a `c`, so `-cmatch`. To match only upper-case letters, I usually use the regex class `\p{Lu}` (`Lu` stands for "**L**etters, **u**pper"):

```
$allUppercase = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path\to\folder\ |Where-Object {$_.Extension -cmatch '^.\p{Lu}+$'}
```

and now you can delete them with `Remove-Item`:

```
$allUppercase |Remove-Item -Force
```

if you want extensions with lowercase only, test for `\p{Ll}`:

```
$allLowercase = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path\to\folder\ |Where-Object {$_.Extension -cmatch '^.\p{Ll}+$'}
```

Comment: Why are you answering this clearly off-topic question?

Comment: Dude, you are my hero, this works perfectly as I I need to. I just have to look into how to prompt user for an input, throw a condition in there and I'll be done. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @aschipfl it might not have been very well written, but it certainly wasn't off topic

Comment: Well, the question is too broad and there is no own research shown; anyway, we'll see whether it's going to be close-voted...